# ghostscript 9.26 update breaks imagick readImage for multipage PDF

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

Since the ghostscript update 9.25 -> 9.26 (on debian) last morning we get this error:

```
ErrorMessage: FailedToExecuteCommand 
`'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT
 -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 
'-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r300x300' 
-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-39903EapVvuyNQxL4%d' 
'-f/tmp/magick-39903VD0GMIpLPaIN' 
'-f/tmp/magick-399031owlSOb4aOEw'' (-1) 
@ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462
```

When trying to read the first page of a multipage PDF:

```
$this->resource = new \Imagick();
$this->resource->setResolution(300, 300);
$this->resource->readImage($path . '[0]');
```

any idea how this problem can be solved?

See: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.26/History9.htm#Version9.26
See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php

Comment: Btw. another error causing problem with this update was that Imagick `scaleImage` resets the value of `setImageDepth`. So make sure to set the depth at the end of your image operations.

Comment: This answer in this other question worked for me, so this question could be closed as duplicate and that answer accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550273/4447371

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly this bug report:

https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699815

Your solutions are; don't use the pngalpha device, don't use FirstPage/LastPage, upgrade to a version with the fix, or downgrade to an earlier version. Though that bug is potentially present in many earlier versions, I don't know why it hasn't exhibited before.

Comment: I ran into this issue trying to use imagemagick with ghostscript via Ruby's MiniMagick gem. Since that doesn't allow me to control the parameters being sent to imagemagick, I had to downgrade ghostscript to 9.25 which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have "a solution" but can confirm the problem since upgrading to gs 9.26. I figured out, that, as KenS pointed out, everything works fine when removing the parameters -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 in gs.

What also works is to remove the gs-parameter -dMaxBitmap=500000000. Meaning in PHP, remove the [PAGE] i.e.:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->readImage('/tmp/test.pdf');
```

My Working solution was a downgrade to ghostscript 9.22. I am using Ubuntu bionic LTS. Therefore I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get remove ghostscript
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install ghostscript=9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1 libgs9=9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1 libgs9-common=9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1
sudo apt-mark auto libgs9
sudo apt-mark auto libgs9-common
```

Comment: I followed ur instructions to get back to 9.22 and it works! Thanks. Also, exactly how do you remove parameters, like dLast/FirstPage?

Comment: When using PHP it is (as far as I know) not possible to change the parameter used in the background. I guess to "remove the dLast/FirstPage Parameter" you just have to call Imagick without the Pageinformation. I.e. $im->readImage('/tmp/test.pdf'); instead of $im->readImage('/tmp/test.pdf[0]');

Answer (score 0):

(Ghostscript 9.26) Had the same problem, after increasing setResolution(600, 600) started working again.

Answer (score -1):

2023: On the ghostcript bin folder, i duplicated the gswin64c and renamed the copy to gs.exe. Worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).