# Imagick fails to execute gs command

Tags: ghostscript, imagick

I can successfully convert some pdfs to pngs but some throw this error:

> ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr
>   -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r144x144' -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-966AGfRi74eBSiG%d'
>   '-f/tmp/magick-966t0bB45paDzcW' '-f/tmp/magick-966l4St1G1Jfh6b'' (-1)
>   @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462

I have a hard time to move forward as I don't understand nothing of the error msg.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting that same error in Ubuntu using ghostscript version 9.26. After additionally installing ghostscript-x with `apt-get update && apt-get install -y ghostscript-x` the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of this question:

[ghostscript 9.26 update breaks imagick readImage for multipage PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560755/ghostscript-9-26-update-breaks-imagick-readimage-for-multipage-pdf)

But I can't mark this as a duplicate as the answer has neither been accepted or upvoted.

Comment: In my case I seem to be able to convert multi-page pdfs but not single page

Comment: Nevertheless, I suspect its the same problem. IIRC its a memory problem so your mileage may vary. Try any of the solutions I suggested in my answer to that question (you can invoke Ghostscript from the command shell using the command line you posted in your question to test these). I'd try using the png16m device instead of the pngalpha device first myself.

Comment: Srry for noobidity but how do I change that?

Comment: I cannot tell you how to change anything to do with ImageMagick (because its an application I'm in utter ignorance of). If you want to change the command line and test GS from the shell, change the -sDEVICE=pngalpha to -sDEVICE=png16m. If you want to try dropping the FirstPage and LastPage, just remove the -dFirstPage=1 and -dLastPage=1. To try a different version of Ghostscript you'll either need to downgrade your existing copy (can't tell you how to do that either) or build the code from source, there is no newer release yet.